# Mysql CASE WHEN JOIN Statement Error

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `pet_info` LEFT JOIN
     `lostpets`
     ON `pet_info`.`id` = `lostpets`.`petid` LEFT JOIN
     `pet_images`
     ON `pet_info`.`id` = `pet_images`.`petid` 
     CASE WHEN `pet_info`.`pet_cat` = 2
          THEN LEFT JOIN `cat_breeds`
               ON `cat_breeds`.`id` = `pet_info`.`pet_breed`
         WHEN `pet_info`.`pet_cat` = 1
         THEN LEFT JOIN `dog_breeds`
              ON `dog_breeds`.`id` = `pet_info`.`pet_breed`
WHERE `pet_info`.`pet_user_id` = 581
```

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN `pet_info`.`pet_cat` = 2 THEN LEFT JOIN `cat_breeds` ON `cat_breeds`.`' at line 1
```

How can I solve error? Where is a error? Please help me.

Comment: This is simply not what `CASE` does.  It is a scalar expression that returns a value, not a conditional construct in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 3):

I think you intend:

```
SELECT *
FROM `pet_info` LEFT JOIN
     `lostpets`
     ON `pet_info`.`id` = `lostpets`.`petid` LEFT JOIN
     `pet_images`
     ON `pet_info`.`id` = `pet_images`.`petid` LEFT JOIN
     `cat_breeds`
     ON `cat_breeds`.`id` = `pet_info`.`pet_breed` AND
        `pet_info`.`pet_cat` = 2 LEFT JOIN
     `dog_breeds`
     ON `dog_breeds`.`id` = `pet_info`.`pet_breed` AND
        `pet_info`.`pet_cat` = 1
WHERE `pet_info`.`pet_user_id` = 581;
```

Notes:

- With a query like this, you should not use `SELECT *`, you should explicitly choose the columns you want.  The different tables have columns with the same name.
- You should use column aliases.  I didn't put these into the query, but they are a good idea.
- In a real query, you would have expressions in the `SELECT` to combine columns from `cat_breeds` and `dog_breeds`, such as `COALESCE(cat_breeds.col1, dog_breeds.col1) as col1`.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`pet_info`.`pet_cat` = 1 WHERE `pet_info`.`pet_user_id` = 581 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1